# Fetching Values for subojjects

Tags: rally

I'm trying to fetch the values for testcase result using the following query

```
queryConfig[0] = {
      type : 'testcase', 
      key : 'tc',
      query: '(Tags.Name contains OS_Windows)', 
      fetch: 'Name,Results'
     };
```

However, the data returned contains an empty Results Object. I'm trying to fetch the values for the build in the resul. "fetch : Results.Build" return invalid character in fetch.

How can I fetch the values for the Results object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch subfields by just including all the fields you'd like to have returned at any level.  So in your case Name,Results,Build will work.  Even though TestCase doesn't have a Build attribute it will be correctly returned on the Results sub objects.

Fetch works this way for all object types.